# Find vector equation of a line that passes through a point and is perpendicular to vector

Tags: vectors

Find the vector equation of line that passes through $(2,1,1)$ and is perpendicular to vector $d=(1,0,1)$

Any hint on solving this problem?
what I have thought of is $(1,0,1)* \text{perpendicular Vector}=0$, but I can't seem to derive it

Comment: Where is the plane in your question?

Comment: I assume it is vector d instead

Comment: Thank you, but then I think you should change the head of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector $\;(a,b,c)\;$ is perpendicular to $\;(1,0,1)\;$ iff

$$(a,b,c)\cdot(1,0,1)=0\iff a+c=0$$

So just choose one such vector and the line you want is simply

$$(2,1,1)+t(a,b,c)\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R$$

Comment: is there anyway to derive (a,b,c)? and also what about the zero vector

Comment: @user317339 The zero vector is perpendicular to any other vector, but it doesn't work in this case (check this). As for how to derive the vector: it is written in the answer.

Comment: so, a=1 and c=-1 is alright? thanks!